# Java Google appengine datastore.get throws EntityNotFoundException on an existing entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, google-cloud-datastore

Looking for ideas on How could it be that I am getting an EntityNotFoundException when trying to get an entity that I know exists by its key.

[image: Screenshot showing admin console with Entity and exception]

As you can see in the screenshot I have an entity of kind "Qualifier" that has an ID/Name of `99_999_9993#5678` but getting an exception saying "No entity was found matching the key: Qualifier("99_999_9993#5678")"

I don't think that it is relevant but just for completeness...:
The entity is created inside a transaction and also has an ancestor (Entity Group).
The get request is a simple non transnational get based on a manually created key.

Any idea on why do I get this EntityNotFoundException instead of getting the entity ?

Comment: Can you show us your code for getting your entity?

Comment: does the key that you use to get the entity contain the ancestor ?

Comment: koma, you are right. I did not have it and though I have actually discovered it on my own (and wrote an answer describing it) I appreciate your comment as its just on the mark.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I though was not relevant was actually very relevant.
When I created the entity I created a key for its ancestor using the KeyFactory but when I was getting it I only used its own part of the key.

As soon as I changed it to use

```
Key groupKey=KeyFactory.createKey(Kinds.Group, group_id);
Key key=KeyFactory.createKey(groupKey,Kinds.Qualifier, qualifier_id );
```

instead of

```
Key key=KeyFactory.createKey(Kinds.Qualifier, qualifier_id );
```

It started returning my Entity as expected.

so basically its important to note that the Datastore Viewer ID/Name shows only the local part of the  keyname, ignoring any indication of the fact that there is an ancestor (Entity Group)...